# Sending an array of numbers over TCP

Tags: arrays, tcp, numbers

I'm trying to send an array of numbers over a TCP socket but they are coming out incorrect. I can't figure out why it's not receiving the correct numbers. Here's what I have ...

Client

```
// the number array to be sent
unsigned long numArray[10] = { htonl(1), htonl(2), htonl(3), htonl(4), htonl(5), 
                               htonl(6), htonl(7), htonl(8), htonl(9), htonl(10) };
send(s, &numArray[0], sizeof(numArray), 0);
```

Server

```
// get the array of numbers
unsigned long numberArray[10];
int numberData = recv(new_fd, numberArray, sizeof(numberArray), 0);
if(numberData == -1) {
  cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}
unsigned long* num = numberArray;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfIncomingData; i++) {
  // this outputs a bunch of huge numbers, none of which are right...
  cout << ntohl(*(num+i)) << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should include a sample of _how_ the numbers are wrong.  What exactly is received?

Comment: This is what prints out on the server side...

269107200
100663296
1074806784
2752864256
269107200
677421903
3222364160
2963820150
3155255296
906969088

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my problem was coming from the previous data that was sent. The size being sent and the size received was different and therefore the entire array got messed up. Thank you for your advice everyone, can't believe I didn't catch that sooner...

Answer (score 3):

A couple of things to start off with;

1) You're not checking either the return value of `send()` or `recv()` for incomplete reads or writes, they may not send or receive the actual number of bytes you give them, they return a value of how many were actually sent/received.

2) `long` is not guaranteed to be the same size on both sides of the connection, it is normally either 32 or 64 bits. `htonl` returns `uint32_t` which is always 32 bits, and your transmitted/received array should use that type too to be architecture independent.

Comment: I decided to print out send and receive and it looks like send() is returning 80 and recv() is returning 0. Is recv() supposed to return the size of the incoming data? If so, it seems it is not getting the array at all...

Comment: @dharris001 It would seem the data isn't getting received, no... recv returning 0 normally means that there is no more data to receive on the socket and it's been closed. I think you need to show how you handle the bind/accept to get the connected socket, there may be something wrong there.

Comment: Well I have been able to send and receive data in this same manner in the code before this example. Interestingly enough, if I loop through the array and send each value individually it makes it over to the server just fine. It is only when I pass the entire array that things get messed up - I'm not sure why that would make a difference. I figured I was pointing to the array incorrectly maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers, converted to hex, are:

```
10 0A 40 00
06 00 00 00
40 10 40 00
0A 15 60 00
10 0A 40 00
28 60 A3 4F
C0 11 60 00
```

These aren't your numbers at all but some sort of data stream.  `10` is DLE, `0A` is a line-feed, and `40` is "@".  Later data isn't your numbers, either.

TCP does not insert any data like this.  You need to check that nothing else is being written to your outgoing socket and that you're reading from the correct incoming socket.